# How to force “Text scaling” with CSS?

Tags: html, css, zooming

Today’s browsers offer two types of zoom:

- Text scaling (<kbd>ctrl +/-</kbd> / <kbd>cmd +/-</kbd>)
- Page zoom (<kbd>ctrl wheel</kbd> / <kbd>cmd wheel</kbd> / <kbd>trackpad pinch</kbd>)

Is it possible to force “Text scaling” even if the user has chosen “Page zoom”?

I’d like a CSS based solution, but I’m open to other solutions (`<meta>` tag, js, ...).

---

I want to change the **zoom type** and not react based on the **zoom level**.
So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, it's not possible.